# Multithumb-Slider in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, slider

Hello dear Stackoverflow Community,

I was looking for something like a multithumbslider in JavaFX, but couldn't find anything. I have a bar chart displaying the grades of an exam, and below that I would like to implement a multithumbslider (or if you have any other suggestions) where I can slide the points which are needed for each grade, so that the chart changes, depending on the changes of the multithumbslider.
Did i state my intentions clear...anyhow?
Does anyone have any ideas on that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, but you can have a look at [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/) which is a libaray which supply controls which are not available in JavaFX by default. They also have a [`RangeSlider`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.html)

[image]

You can use their code to write your own `MultiThumbSlider`. This Control is mainly made up of two classes the `RangeSlider` and the `RangeSliderSkin`. The code can be found here:

[`org.controlsfx.control.RangeSlider`](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/aca01560384c835a6df2536378cdd0a0602f8a8c/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/control/RangeSlider.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

[`impl.org.controlsfx.skin.RangeSliderSkin`](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/aca01560384c835a6df2536378cdd0a0602f8a8c/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/skin/RangeSliderSkin.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default)

You can also find all other classes reqiured there.

Comment: Thank you very much, kind sir. I will have a look into this and then mark your answer with a check. :-)
I found something for swing, but that is a thing of the past, I guess.